# How do I negate a phrase in a code generated regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression that's generated with some java code. It's used to count the occurrences of a long list of words.

Data:

> I'm interested in doing something enjoyable and fun. I'm not
>   interested in anything that is not exciting. Please keep me
>   interested.

Example:

```
\b(interested|fun|enjoyable|exciting)\b
```

Count would be: interested (3) + fun(1) + enjoyable(1) + exciting(1) Total:6

I want to ignore defined phrases that I don't think should be included in the count. It could be anything. In this case I want to exclude "not interested" and "not exciting."

The tricky part is I have this generated in code, so I want the process to be pretty simple and reliable.

Comment: And will `not` also be variable? For example, do you want to exclude things like `not so interested`, `less interested` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking only for a *count* of key words / phrases, the easiest approach would probably be to get that count as you already do, and then compute a count of wider phrases from which you want to exclude matches.  Subtract the count of the latter from the count of the former.

A general rule for determining wider phrases to excluded could be a complex exercise in computational linguistics, but if you only want to exclude the matched phrases when they are preceded by "not", then that's relatively easy:

```
String keywordsSubPattern = "\b(interested|fun|enjoyable|exciting)\b";
String negatedKeywordsSubPattern = "\bnot\s+" + keywordsSubPattern;

int keywordCount = countOfMatchesToPattern(keywordsSubPattern)
        - countOfMatchesToPattern(negatedKeywordsSubPattern);
```

You could do this a bit more cleanly by inserting a negative lookbehind assertion into the keyword pattern, so that it didn't match the negated versions in the first place, but lookbehind assertions cannot be used with patterns that match variable-length sequences.  `\bnot\s+` is such a pattern on account of the `+` quantifier.  But if you wanted to exclude only keywords preceded by "not" and *exactly one* whitespace character then you might do something like this:

```
String keywordsSubPattern = "\b(interested|fun|enjoyable|exciting)\b";
String unnegatedKeywordsSubPattern = "(?<!\bnot\s)" + keywordsSubPattern;

int keywordCount = countOfMatchesToPattern(unnegatedkeywordsSubPattern);
```

Comment: Great solution. This was sort of what we were thinking but it creates the issue where let's say the sentence is "This is not interesting but it is exciting." If "not interesting" is counted as -1 and "exciting" is counted as 1 then the count would be zero when it should be 1. We want to ignore specific phrases.

Comment: @JoshuaHedges, you are overlooking the key point: "not interesting" would be counted by *both* patterns, so that the subtraction yields a net 0 contribution from it (not -1) to the overall score.